# Change Camera Settings for the Camera2 API android

Tags: android, settings, iso, android-camera2

I am using the [android-camera2-secret-picture-taker](https://github.com/hzitoun/android-camera2-secret-picture-taker)
and getting the image which is dark and not able to change the whiteblance in capture builder.
Here is what changing I have made to capturebuilder:

/**Settings for Camera*/
//        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation());

```
    /**HDR*/
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_SCENE_MODE_HDR);

    /**Settings for Flash*/
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO);

/**for White Balance */
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS, colorTemperature(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO));

//for incandescent
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_INCANDESCENT);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS, colorTemperature(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_INCANDESCENT));
//        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS, CameraCapabilities.colorTemperature(Integer.parseInt(awbMode)));

//for daylight
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_DAYLIGHT);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS, colorTemperature(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_DAYLIGHT));
        }

//for fluorescent
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_FLUORESCENT);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS, colorTemperature(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_FLUORESCENT));}

//for cloudy
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_CLOUDY_DAYLIGHT);
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS, colorTemperature(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_CLOUDY_DAYLIGHT));

/**For ISO*/
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL);
    CameraCharacteristics mCameraCharacteristics = characteristics;
    List keys_list = characteristics.getKeys();
    Range<Integer> range2 = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE);
    int iso = ((200 * (200 - 100)) / 100 + 100);
    if (range2 != null) {
        int max1 = range2.getUpper();//10000
        int min1 = range2.getLower();//100
        iso = ((max1 * (max1 - min1)) / 100 + min1);
    }
    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, iso);
```

I am not able to change the brightness, and other settings except the FlashMode.

Comment: any update on this

Comment: *I am not able to change the brightness* - you get an error? Or this change does not show up in the picture? Note that support for all these parameters in `CaptureBuilder.set()` is optional, only *somewhat* guaranteed for devices that report being [HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL) devices in the [android.info.supportedHardwareLevel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL) key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for "Auto Exposure" since you're talking about brightness. Therefore, I would suggest you to use:

```
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, 4);
// play around with the "4" which is the amount of brightness you want compensate by.
```